# Path to jQuery file for SharePointWebControls:ScriptLink

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, javascript, jquery, page-layout

I'm working in SharePoint 2010 Designer to create a custom page layout. I've added a `SharePointWebControls:ScriptLink` control but am not sure what the path is to my jQuery library. It's uploaded to the root collection's Site Assets, in subfolders `/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js`.

The absolute URL to it is `http://vmdev195/SiteAssets/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js`. Is there a way to give a relative path to this file in the ScriptLink control? This way the page will work on different servers that have the same folder/file structure. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working in SharePoint Designer, then you can use a plain old  tag instead and reference the .js file anywhere you want:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

Any relative path will work, whether it's in _layouts, a Document Library, or an external CDN.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. That worked beautifully :) For some reason, I forgot that the client-side options are available in `asp:Content` areas. Plus, Designer allows you to pick the file and it'll generate the path automatically. Very nice.

Comment: [update] caveat: For 2013 MDS enabled sites, script tags won't work, use RegisterSOD or ScriptLink.

Comment: They still work, don't they? I seem to remember using them just fine, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this?

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<!-- ... -->

<SharePoint:ScriptLink runat="server" Name="/SiteAssets/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" Localizable="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks, omlin. I've seen the `SharePoint:ScriptLink` tag but couldn't figure out what the difference is between that and the `SharePointWebControls:ScriptLink` tag.

Comment: That doesn't work; it throws this error, even though the file is there: `Cannot make a cache safe URL for "1033//siteassets/global/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js", file not found. Please verify that the file exists under the layouts directory.` What does work is this: http://sensoft2000-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/09/error-cannot-make-cache-safe-url-for.html. Not the most convenient way to do it, but it works.

Comment: Alex, I'm afraid you simply forget about `Localizable="false"` attribute.. That's why you're getting "1033" attached in front of the url.

Comment: For 2013 (v15) and current SharePoint Online (v16) you need to use a url token to get a site relative reference for the name property, like `~site/SiteAssets/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js`